# Shiny passwordInput causes problem with selectInput

Tags: r, shiny

Using Shiny passwordInput causes a problem with selectInput. When the example below loads, the selectInput selected item has an extra character added. Also, and the more noticeable problem, when I either select a saved a password using my browser or refresh the page, the selectInput dropdown opens spontaneously. In my larger app, this issue presents itself as dropdown menus of some selectInputs opening spontaneously. Any workarounds for this?

```
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    selectInput(inputId = "mySelectInput", label = "My Select Input", choices = letters),
    passwordInput(inputId = "myPasswordInput", label = "Password")
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {}
)
```

[image]

**Update**

Using Chrome: Version 106.0.5249.119 (Official Build) (64-bit)

R sessionInfo():

```
R version 4.1.3 (2022-03-10)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas/libblas.so.3.9.0
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack/liblapack.so.3.9.0

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=C.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C           LC_TIME=C.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=C.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=C.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=C.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=C.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C             
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C           LC_TELEPHONE=C         LC_MEASUREMENT=C.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C   

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] shiny_1.7.3

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.9       withr_2.5.0      digest_0.6.30    later_1.3.0      mime_0.12        R6_2.5.1        
 [7] jsonlite_1.8.2   lifecycle_1.0.3  xtable_1.8-4     magrittr_2.0.3   cachem_1.0.6     rlang_1.0.6     
[13] cli_3.4.1        rstudioapi_0.14  promises_1.2.0.1 jquerylib_0.1.4  bslib_0.4.0      ellipsis_0.3.2  
[19] tools_4.1.3      httpuv_1.6.6     fastmap_1.1.0    compiler_4.1.3   memoise_2.0.1    htmltools_0.5.3 
[25] sass_0.4.2      
>
```

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this error, its working as it should. Can you give more info about the operating system and the version of the browser that you are using?

Comment: @jpdugo17 updated post with browser info and output of sessionInfo()

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem either